# How can I have a function triggered by pressing any key in Javascript?

Tags: javascript

I am trying to be able to have some text display and when you have read it you can press any key the text will be replaced with new text. Can somebody help?Thanks!

Comment: Please show some code that you have tried. If you want others to write full code for you, you should consider hiring a freelancer. Please take some time to visit the [help center](http://stackoverflow.com/help) and also read [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), so you can learn what types of questions are accepted here, how to write questions, and how to use this site effectively

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can use the keydown event by attaching it to the document [DOM]

Something like this :

```js
document.onkeydown = function(evt) {
    evt = evt || window.event;
    alert(evt.keyCode); // this will give you the code of key which was pressed
    //myFunction()
    //You can also call your custom function here
};
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/keydown